# Real part of $\sinh(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers, hyperbolic-geometry

Is it true that for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$

$$\begin{align}
&2\mathfrak{Re}(\sinh z) &= \sinh z + \sinh \bar z\\
&2i\cdot \mathfrak{Im}(\sinh z) &= \sinh z - \sinh \bar z
\end{align}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Michael. We will certainly help you - but to make it in a better way, could you tell what are the confusing points for you? E.g. would you put here how did you derive these formulas?

Comment: It was a step in a solution I was trying to follow.
The question itself was about proving a function to be harmonic and finding it's conjugate.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true because the coefficients of the power series expansion of these entire functions are real.